# Defining/restricting ArcToolbox script tool input parameters to specific types

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python-script-tool, arctoolbox

I've created an arcpy script (that works fine) that runs on a geodatabase (mdb, gdb, enterprise), or can also be run on a Feature Dataset within a geodatabase.

In my script tool properties in ArcToolbox I have set my Input as "Workspace or Feature Dataset" which allows me to add either as my input and the script will run.

However, the "Workspace" part of this property seems to be quite broad, in that I can also add folders, DWG drawing files, probably other types of data into the input field.  So, I would like to limit this input property to ONLY accept Geodatabases or Feature Datasets.

Is there another option I can pick that will limit to one of these two?  Or a way to use Validation or Parameter Filter to restrict the input types?  The parameter Filter option for Workspace of Feature Dataset only gives the option `None`

[image]

This is in ArcGIS Desktop 10.8